# How to set CardView width equals to nested TextView width

Tags: android, android-cardview

I created a `CardView` widget, inside of which a `TextView` is. The text of the `TextView` changes in the runtime. How can I bind my `CardView` width to the `TextView` width?

**What I have tried so far:**

In the `CardView`, I added, `android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textViewUser"` but it doesn't work as the `TextView` can't be nested using this method. Any idea?

A snippet of the `CardView` item is the following. Please note I removed the constraints to make it shorter.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardViewUser"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:elevation="14dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="I change during runtime"
                android:id="@+id/textViewUser"/>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How about setting the `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` in your `CardView`? Does that help?

Comment: @Treewallie thank you so much for mentioning this, I thought the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to keep width of the CardView connected with the TextView. You can try something like this:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardViewUser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:elevation="14dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="I change during runtime"
            android:id="@+id/textViewUser"/>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```